# Assigning function output to a wire produces X's in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm building a module in System Verilog, and I created a function to check the boundary cases. However, instead of returning the expected value, it returns X. I shrank my code down, and I ended up with the code snippet below. I am somewhat new to System Verilog, so I'm curious if there is some syntax for the function I'm missing that causes it to return X. I have been simulating my code on EDAPlayground using VCS 2014.12 and with the SVunit 2.11 library.

```
  module testfunction (); 
  reg  state_value;
  wire function_state, raw_state;

  // function state will always be x's (should be same as raw_state)
  assign function_state = boundary_check(0);

  // raw works correctly (normal assignment method)
  assign raw_state = state_value;

  initial
    begin
      state_value = 1'b0;
    end

  function boundary_check(input integer row);
    if((row < 2) && (row >= 0))
      boundary_check = state_value;
    else
      boundary_check = 1'b0;
  endfunction

endmodule
```

I have tried making function_state a reg and putting it in an always block, but that still returned X.

Comment: From SystemVerilog LRM : **always_comb is sensitive to changes within the contents of a function, whereas always @* is only
sensitive to changes to the arguments of a function.** So, `always_comb` might be a better alternative here.

Answer (score 1):

It should have worked if you used an `always_comb` construct. The problem with your function is it only has constant input arguments. A continuous `assign` statement only evaluates when a signal on the RHS of the assignment has a change event. The `always_comb` construct expands function calls in-line, so it will see a signal change that appears inside the function.

You could also make `state_value` an input to the function and keep the continuous assign construct.

P.S. If you are using SystemVerilog, use `logic` instead of `reg` or `wire`. Only use `wire` when you have multiple drivers and need strength resolution.